# Laravel + Doctrine - get nearest place by ST_DISTANCE

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, doctrine-orm

I want to find minimum distance between region's point and my point. I search about it and find [ST_CONTAIN](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-to-find-nearest-neighbors-between-two-tables-with-point-locations-in-spatial), However when I use this function , I get an error :

```
Expected known function, got 'ST_Distance'
```

Here is my code:

```
public function getNearestPlace(Point $point)
{
    $neighborhoods = $this->_em
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('Region')
        ->from($this->entityClass, 'Region')
        ->where(
            '
                MIN (ST_Distance(
                    Region.regionMapCenter, 
                    GeomFromText(\'POINT(' . $point . ')\')
                ) > 0
            '
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
    return $neighborhoods;
}
```

How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine is shipped with [some functions out-of-the-box](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) but distance functions are not among them. You can define your own functions though, this might be useful for your case. Documentation for this can be found [in chapter **14.5.5. Adding your own functions to the DQL language**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language)

I also found [a nice blog post](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/02/19/using-spatial-data-in-doctrine-2/) on how to add distance functionality to your application. Maybe this blogpost will be helpful too. The distance function from the blog post looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Wantlet\ORM;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * DQL function for calculating distances between two points
 *
 * Example: DISTANCE(foo.point, POINT_STR(:param))
 */
class Distance extends FunctionNode {
    private $firstArg;
    private $secondArg;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) {
        //Need to do this hacky linestring length thing because
        //despite what MySQL manual claims, DISTANCE isn't actually implemented...
        return 'GLength(LineString(' .
               $this->firstArg->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
               ', ' .
               $this->secondArg->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
           '))';
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->firstArg = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->secondArg = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```